# Flutter dropdown button selected value position

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-getx, flutter-dropdownbutton

How can I make the selected dropdown item appear first in the list when its opened?
I'm using GetX for state,

is this the proper way of doing it anyway?

**This is the code:**

```
var dropdownvalue = 'Default'.obs;
  var items = [
    'Default',
    'Difficulty',
    'Time',
    'Distance',
  ];
  RxInt selectedIndex = 0.obs;
```

...

```
Obx(() => DropdownButton(
                    value: dropdownvalue.value,
                    items: items.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: items,
                        child: Text(items),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      dropdownvalue.value = value.toString();
                    },
                  )
```

**This is how it looks now:**

[image]

The list should stay in one place when its opened, and values should change places.

Edit: now it shows the same value

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should rearrange your list after selecting an item

```
onChanged: (value) {
  dropdownvalue.value = value.toString();
  items.remove("Time");
  items.insert(0, "Time");
  setState((){});
},
```

Comment: this does the trick, it could get confusing cause the order is different every time you pick a different option

Comment: yeah, but you can make a temp list with the original items and every time you select an item from the drop down you put that item in the first and assign this temp list to the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected value = "";

initState(){
value = dropdownvalue.value;
}

    Obx(() => DropdownButton(
                        value: dropdownvalue.value,
                        items: items.map((String items) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: items,
                            child: Text( value), //changes here 
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          dropdownvalue.value = value.toString();
                        },
                      )


Change there your problem will be solved
```

Comment: It didn't do the trick unfortunately, I added images so you can see the problem.

Comment: i have changed the answer can you try with initialise e value like this

Comment: did you change anything?  I didn't notice changes, tried again but the same problem emerges